# I can't insert a video

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

I use galp and webpack collectors on my project, I don't understand why I can't insert a video. Although if you use a simple live server then everything works

```
<video id="video" width="100%" height="auto" autoplay loop preload="auto">
    <source src="/src/APEK - Exposed (Official Music Video) ft. April Bender(1080p).mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
    <source src="/sample-5s.webm" type="video/webm"></source>
  </video>
```

Error:
GET http://192.168.1.9:8080/src/APEK%20-%20Exposed%20(Official%20Music%20Video)%20ft.%20April%20Bender(1080p).mp4 404 (Not Found)
192.168.1.9/:869          GET http://192.168.1.9:8080/src/APEK%20-%20Exposed%20(Official%20Music%20Video)%20ft.%20April%20Bender(1080p).mp4 404 (Not Found)
192.168.1.9/:869          GET http://192.168.1.9:8080/sample-5s.webm 404 (Not Found)
192.168.1.9/:869          GET http://192.168.1.9:8080/sample-5s.webm 404 (Not Found)

I will be glad if you help, thank you in advance

Comment: looks to me like your file path in the `src` is incorrect

Comment: *a simple live server* in dev will mount the project directory to `/` so `./src` will be accessible, once you build then the live server wont be running and most likely your build tools are building from ./src not from ./ so src wont exist in dist etc.

Comment: Ugh -- For Pete's sake --  Take the the spaces out of your file names.  Take the dots out of your file names.  You'll be a more sane person for it.